Anyone here who knows how to implement client auth interceptor in flutter? Am using grpc or an alternative on how i can manage authentication
I am using grpc+protocol buffers in Flutter Mobile Client. My question is how can I add interceptors to grpc request/responses so that I will be able to log as much as I want from the same place? I also need to send these request/responses to another client for some purpose. Any better approach is highly appreciated
class AuthInterceptor extends ClientInterceptor {
  final AuthStorage authStorage;
  final List<String> excludedPaths;

   AuthInterceptor(this.authStorage, {this.excludedPaths = const []});
@override
  ResponseFuture<R> interceptUnary<Q, R>(
    ClientMethod<Q, R> method,
    Q request,
    CallOptions options,
    ResponseFuture<R> Function(ClientMethod<Q, R>, Q, CallOptions) invoker,
  ) {
    if (!excludedPaths.contains(method.path)) {
      final token = authStorage.getAuthInfo();
      {
        options = options.mergedWith(
          CallOptions(metadata: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}),
        );
      }
      return invoker(method, request, options);
    }

    @override
    ResponseStream<R> interceptStreaming<Q, R>(
      ClientMethod<Q, R> method,
      Stream<Q> requests,
      CallOptions options,
      ResponseStream<R> Function(ClientMethod<Q, R>, Stream<Q>, CallOptions)
          invoker,
    ) async {
      if (!excludedPaths.contains(method.path)) {
        final token = await authStorage.getAuthInfo();
        if (token != null) {
          options = options.mergedWith(
            CallOptions(metadata: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'}),
          );
        }
      }
      return invoker(method, requests, options);
    }
  }
}


would it be possible to add some code snippet you tried?
